# Access ArrayList populated in one class, in another class

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class called World that has an `ArrayList` called entities, the data is then added to the list and displayed on the map. The `ArrayList` needs accessible from another class called Player that also needs to iterate through the list to be able to check if the is intersecting it. What I want to know is how to make the entities `ArrayList` accessible to the Player class.

the list in the World.java is

```
public List<Entity> entities; // contains all entities
```

the ArrayList is being initialized in World.java

```
entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();// initialise list to new array list
```

data being hardcoded into this list in World.java

```
Transform r1 = new Transform();
r1.position.x = 4;
r1.position.y = -4;

Transform r2 = new Transform();
r2.position.x = 5;
r2.position.y = -7;

Transform r3 = new Transform();
r3.position.x = 11;
r3.position.y = -12;

Transform r4 = new Transform();
r4.position.x = 10;
r4.position.y = -8;

Transform t1 = new Transform();
t1.position.x = 3;
t1.position.y = -7;

Transform t2 = new Transform();
t2.position.x = 5;
t2.position.y = -5;

Transform t3 = new Transform();
t3.position.x = 13;
t3.position.y = -13;

Transform t4 = new Transform();
t4.position.x = 7;
t4.position.y = -5;

Transform t5 = new Transform();
t4.position.x = 8;
t4.position.y = -9;

Transform t6 = new Transform();
t4.position.x = 14;
t4.position.y = -14;

entities.add(new Player(new Transform()));// add entity player

entities.add(new Rock(r1));// add entity rock
entities.add(new Rock(r3));// add entity rock

entities.add(new Rock(r2));// add entity rock

entities.add(new Rock(r4));// add entity rock

entities.add(new Tree(t1));// add entity rock
entities.add(new Tree(t3));// add entity rock

entities.add(new Tree(t2));// add entity rock

entities.add(new Tree(t4));// add entity rock

entities.add(new Tree(t5));// add entity rock

entities.add(new Tree(t6));// add entity rock

the list being iterated in World.java

for (Entity entity : entities) {// itaarate through all the entities in list of entities
    entity.render(shader, camera, this);// render each entity
    if (!entity.isActive())
        entities.remove(entity);


}
```

Player.java class

```
public class Player extends Entity {

    public ArrayList<Entity> entities; // contains all entities
    public static final int IDLE = 0;
    public static final int RUN = 1;

    public Player(Transform transform) {
        super(4, transform);
        // number of images, fps, file
        setAnimation(IDLE, new Animations(4, 2, "player/idle"));// player standing
        setAnimation(RUN, new Animations(4, 4, "player/run"));// player walking

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float delta, Window window, Camera camera, World world) {
        Vector2f movement = new Vector2f();// gets new position

        if (window.getInput().isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_A))
            movement.add(-10 * delta, 0);// move character 10 units fr every frame

        if (window.getInput().isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_D))
            movement.add(10 * delta, 0);// move character 10 units fr every frame
        if (window.getInput().isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_W))
            movement.add(0, 10 * delta);// move character 10 units fr every frame

        if (window.getInput().isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_S))
            movement.add(0, -10 * delta);// move character 10 units fr every frame


        Rectangle cb = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle ar = new Rectangle();
        int arSize = 20;
        ar.width = arSize;
        ar.height = arSize;

        if (window.getInput().isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UP))
            ar.x = cb.x + cb.width / 2 - arSize / 2;
        ar.y = cb.y - arSize;

        if (window.getInput().isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_DOWN))
            ar.x = cb.x + cb.width / 2 - arSize / 2;
        ar.y = cb.y + cb.height;

        if (window.getInput().isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_LEFT))
            ar.x = cb.x - arSize;
        ar.y = cb.y + cb.height / 2 - arSize / 2;

        if (window.getInput().isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_RIGHT))
            ar.x = cb.x + cb.width;
        ar.y = cb.y + cb.height / 2 - arSize / 2;

        for (Entity entity : ) {// itaarate through all the entities in list of entities

        }

        move(movement);
        if (movement.x != 0 || movement.y != 0)
            useAnimation(RUN);
        else
            useAnimation(IDLE);

        camera.getPosition().lerp(transform.position.mul(-world.getScale(), new Vector3f()), 0.1f);// follows the player
    }
}
```

Comment: How are `Player` and `World` related?  Is one inside of the other in some form?  Also _why_ does a `Player` need to know all other `Entities`?

Comment: member var entities is declared public, so just use `for (Entity entity : world.entities)`

Comment: look up "MVC". This is what you need. You need one controller with all of your Model classes so that the controller can coordinate between everything

Answer (score 0):

for example say this is your world class has arraylist in it

```
class World{
private static ArrayList<Entry> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.put(someting);
list.put(someting);
public static ArrayList<Entry> getList(){ // create static method to access list from other class 
 return list;
}
```

Now from class Player

```
ArrayList<Entry> list = Wordl.getList();  // you have the list from world class
```

Comment: Did you try this?  This would not work, you are referencing a non-static field from a `static` context.

Comment: @Nexevis no i didn't test , thanks , editied it now

Comment: Since `list` is public you would be able to access it with `World.list`, you don't need a getter.  Also making the `list` `static` would make the `list` the same for every `World`, which I don't think makes sense.

Comment: @Nexevis i made it private but i encourage , and as name suggest world is supposed to be a singleton but i encourage you to provide a better solution in the answer.

Comment: Why would the name suggest a singleton?  If this is a video game (which the class `Player` would suggest), there would be different `Worlds` for each level with different `Entities` within.  A simple example would be Mario's different "Worlds".  I would provide a better solution, but to do this correctly would take too much effort to completely rework what he is currently doing, it is not just a simple fix (ControlAltDel left a comment that mentions MVC which is where a good implementation could start).

Answer (score 0):

From reading the comments I just needed to make the list static

```
Static public List<Entity> entities; // contains all entities
```

Comment: You _can_ make it `static`, but that is definitely not good design.  Additionally `static` will make `entities` the same for every instance of `World`.  Every `World` has the same entities?  I doubt that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A World object could be composed of many Entity objects. a Player object should not necessarily be composed of the World object. Instead when a Player needs to know about the World, or entities in the world, it should be accessible, for example;

```java
class Entity {

    void update() {

    }

    void update(Entity other) {

    }

}

class World {

    private final List<Entity> entities;

    public World(List<Entity> entities) {
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    public void update() {
        for (Entity entity : entities) {
            entity.update();

            for (Entity other : entities) {
                if (entity == other) {
                    continue;
                }
                update(entity, other);
            }
        }
    }

    public void update(Entity source, Entity target) {
        source.update(target);
    }

}
```